# Compiling kernel from source. error explaination.

Tags: c, kernel

I am compiling an android kernel from source. But getting stuck with some error in making the object `tspdrv.o` and cant make out where it is generating from. Following is the error:

```
  CC      drivers/tspdrv/tspdrv.o
In file included from include/linux/kernel.h:23:0,
             from include/linux/cache.h:4,
             from include/linux/time.h:7,
             from include/linux/stat.h:60,
             from include/linux/module.h:10,
             from drivers/tspdrv/tspdrv.c:34:
drivers/tspdrv/ImmVibeSPI.c: In function 'drv2604_write_reg_val':
include/linux/dynamic_debug.h:61:16: error: implicit declaration of function 'KBUILD_STR' [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
  static struct _ddebug __aligned(8)          \
         ^
include/linux/dynamic_debug.h:73:2: note: in expansion of macro 
'DEFINE_DYNAMIC_DEBUG_METADATA'
  DEFINE_DYNAMIC_DEBUG_METADATA(descriptor, fmt);  \
  ^
include/linux/printk.h:196:2: note: in expansion of macro 'dynamic_pr_debug'
  dynamic_pr_debug(fmt, ##__VA_ARGS__)
  ^
drivers/tspdrv/ImmVibeSPI.c:681:4: note: in expansion of macro 'pr_debug'
pr_debug("drv2604 x5 write 0x%02x, 0x%02x", data[i], data[i + 1]);
^
<command-line>:0:27: error: 'tspdrv' undeclared (first use in this function)
include/linux/dynamic_debug.h:63:14: note: in expansion of macro 'KBUILD_MODNAME'
   .modname = KBUILD_MODNAME,   \
              ^
include/linux/dynamic_debug.h:73:2: note: in expansion of macro 'DEFINE_DYNAMIC_DEBUG_METADATA'
  DEFINE_DYNAMIC_DEBUG_METADATA(descriptor, fmt);  \
  ^
include/linux/printk.h:196:2: note: in expansion of macro 'dynamic_pr_debug'
  dynamic_pr_debug(fmt, ##__VA_ARGS__)
  ^
drivers/tspdrv/ImmVibeSPI.c:681:4: note: in expansion of macro 'pr_debug'
    pr_debug("drv2604 x5 write 0x%02x, 0x%02x", data[i], data[i + 1]);
    ^
<command-line>:0:27: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
include/linux/dynamic_debug.h:63:14: note: in expansion of macro 'KBUILD_MODNAME'
   .modname = KBUILD_MODNAME,   \
              ^
include/linux/dynamic_debug.h:73:2: note: in expansion of macro 'DEFINE_DYNAMIC_DEBUG_METADATA'
  DEFINE_DYNAMIC_DEBUG_METADATA(descriptor, fmt);  \
  ^
include/linux/printk.h:196:2: note: in expansion of macro 'dynamic_pr_debug'
  dynamic_pr_debug(fmt, ##__VA_ARGS__)
  ^
drivers/tspdrv/ImmVibeSPI.c:681:4: note: in expansion of macro 'pr_debug'
    pr_debug("drv2604 x5 write 0x%02x, 0x%02x", data[i], data[i + 1]);
    ^
drivers/tspdrv/ImmVibeSPI.c: In function 'drv2604_read_reg':
<command-line>:0:27: error: 'tspdrv' undeclared (first use in this function)
include/linux/dynamic_debug.h:63:14: note: in expansion of macro 'KBUILD_MODNAME'
   .modname = KBUILD_MODNAME,   \
              ^
include/linux/dynamic_debug.h:73:2: note: in expansion of macro 'DEFINE_DYNAMIC_DEBUG_METADATA'
  DEFINE_DYNAMIC_DEBUG_METADATA(descriptor, fmt);  \
  ^
include/linux/printk.h:196:2: note: in expansion of macro 'dynamic_pr_debug'
  dynamic_pr_debug(fmt, ##__VA_ARGS__)
  ^
drivers/tspdrv/ImmVibeSPI.c:732:2: note: in expansion of macro 'pr_debug'
  pr_debug("drv2604 read addr:0x%x reg:0x%x data:0x%x res:%d",
  ^
cc1: some warnings being treated as errors
scripts/Makefile.build:306: *** [drivers/tspdrv/tspdrv.o] Error 1

#0  drivers/tspdrv/tspdrv.o at 
/home/ozair/nougat_mi3/kernel/xiaomi/cancro/scripts/Makefile.build:306
#1  drivers/tspdrv/built-in.o at 
/home/ozair/nougat_mi3/kernel/xiaomi/cancro/scripts/Makefile.build:374
#2  __build at 
/home/ozair/nougat_mi3/kernel/xiaomi/cancro/scripts/Makefile.build:8
Command-line invocation:
    "remake -f scripts/Makefile.build obj=drivers/tspdrv"
scripts/Makefile.build:442: *** [drivers/tspdrv] Error 2

#0  drivers/tspdrv at 
/home/ozair/nougat_mi3/kernel/xiaomi/cancro/scripts/Makefile.build:442
#1  drivers/pinctrl/built-in.o at 
/home/ozair/nougat_mi3/kernel/xiaomi/cancro/scripts/Makefile.build:361
#2  drivers/built-in.o at 
/home/ozair/nougat_mi3/kernel/xiaomi/cancro/scripts/Makefile.build:374
#3  __build at 
/home/ozair/nougat_mi3/kernel/xiaomi/cancro/scripts/Makefile.build:8
Command-line invocation:
    "remake -f scripts/Makefile.build obj=drivers"
Makefile:949: *** [drivers] Error 2

#0  drivers at 
/home/ozair/nougat_mi3/kernel/xiaomi/cancro/Makefile:949
#1  arch/arm/kernel/vmlinux.lds at 
/home/ozair/nougat_mi3/kernel/xiaomi/cancro/Makefile:940
#2  vmlinux at 
/home/ozair/nougat_mi3/kernel/xiaomi/cancro/Makefile:915
#3  all at /home/ozair/nougat_mi3/kernel/xiaomi/cancro/Makefile:563
#4  _all at /home/ozair/nougat_mi3/kernel/xiaomi/cancro/Makefile:111
Command-line invocation:
   " none
```

I need to understand the root of this error since it is not leading me anywhere. For example lets take this part of the error

```
drivers/tspdrv/ImmVibeSPI.c: In function 'drv2604_write_reg_val':
include/linux/dynamic_debug.h:61:16: error: implicit declaration of 
function 'KBUILD_STR' [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
  static struct _ddebug __aligned(8)          \
         ^
```

There is no function called `KBUILD_STR` in `include/linux/dynamic_debug.h:61:16`

or I am reading it wrong?

Comment: I guess the source code is not complete. Please download the android kernel source again and try to compile it.

Comment: @GauravPathak Unfortunately can't do anything about incomplete source code, I just downloaded what they provided. :(And have tried many times but to no avail. Can changing toolchains work?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like KBUILD_STR was removed from the kernel build scripts somewhere between 4.2 and 4.10.

It looks like the driver has not been updated to match.